# Cups won't start. "Child exited with status 2!"

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I have a NSA-325-v2 miniserver and I want to connect my local computers to the server to print.

The connection itself works, I can ssh to the machine, use nfs to handle the file shares, etc.

When I start cups with `/etc/init.d/cups start` I get this ouptut:

```
cupsd: Child exited with status 2!
cups: unable to start scheduler.
```

I checked that the printer works locally with `lpr` and that works fine.

So, is there a way to make cups produce any logs that I then could read? (`/var/log/cups` does not exist, the various Log Parameters in `cupsd.conf` are on default.) I failed to get it to be more verbose and tell me which Child died and why.

The machine runs a Samba Server that was used to printing earlier. It stopped working, but I could not yet figure out why. I'd prefer cups, so that I then would be able to remove the Samba Server altogether.

Comment: I solved the Samba Problem by now, so I won't actively search for solutions anymore. But if you provide one, I'll test it.